# After convert "object" to "float" all values are NaN - how to solve this?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have the following column in my dataset. The Dtype is "object". I want to convert it into a float but could need some help.

```
Value
$166.400,00
$135.200,00
$124.800,00
$124.800,00
$118.809,60
```

First I had separated the $.

```
def split(x):
    return x.split("$")[1]
df["Value_conv"] = df["Value"].apply(split)


Value_conv
166.400,00
135.200,00
124.800,00
124.800,00
118.809,60
```

After this I tried pd.to_numeric

```
df['Value_conv'] = pd.to_numeric((df['Value_conv']), errors='coerce')
```

The result is that Value_conv now is a float64. But: All values are NAN.

```
Value_conv
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

What do I have to do to convert this column into a float but with the values not NaN? After doing some Google I believe it has something to do with the separators "." and "," but I just can not figure out a way to solve it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: check your comma, dot notation. for python, a dot is what you consider a point and vice versa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because there is a comma. If you want the values before the comma and after the dollar sign, try this:

```
df["Value_conv"] = df["Value"].str.split('$').str[1].str.split(',').str[0].astype(float)
```

The reason it gives `None` is because `errors='coerce'` gives `None` if it's not a integer/float like.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

It says:

> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaN.

Comment: Nice answer but i guess you also need to take care of values after the comma  i.e `cents` :)

Comment: @U11-Forward If you like i can edit the answer ;)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Nah I think it's okay :D